# How does writing more lines into an existing csv file through c work?

Tags: c

My program takes a user's input, encrypts it and then decrypts it upon request (encryption and decryption are through my own logic and work fine).
But when I try to store these in a .csv file (here it's just a placeholder string for now), the program behaves weirdly. It stores the data for the first time but after the second execution the csv file should have two lines ... but it has only one.

What is happening here?
I'm new to filehandling. I can provide more bits of code if required...
The code:

```
main()
{
char pwd[100];
printf("Enter Password To Be Encrypted: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", pwd);
printf("The encrypted password is: ");
encrypt(&pwd);
printf("\n The decrypted password is: ");
decrypt(&pwd);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("storeroom.csv", "w");
fprintf(fp, "placeholder , placeholder\n");
printf("\n Details successfully written to the file\n\n");
fclose(fp);
```

The Terminal output for the first and second execution are given below
first:

```
Enter Password To Be Encrypted: cherrygrove
The encrypted password is:
9(/,7%,,96;
 The decrypted password is:
cherrygrove

Details successfully written to the file**
```

second:

```
Enter Password To Be Encrypted: johto
The encrypted password is: 
/*6/4
 The decrypted password is:
johto
 Details successfully written to the file
```

The csv file should have two lines now... but it has only one:-
[[image]]

Comment: "*It stores the data for the first time but throws this error on subsequent execution*". That does not make sense. The error shown is a *compile time* error. So what do you mean by "first time". If you compile this same code multiple times it should get that same warning every time.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the csv file?? Can you please provide the exact commands leading up to that warning message? And please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: user18025483 please provide the complete compilation log, execution log, a sample CSV file output. "storeroom.csv:1:1: warning:" - It does seem like you are trying to compile the CSV file, not your C file.

Comment: @kaylum@vijay sorry I'll try my best to do something rn. I'm still new sorry...

Comment: Please describe your understanding of the "s" in `"%[^\n]s"`.

Comment: If you can compile your code even once then the shown code is not a [mre].

Comment: You now describe two executions in the second part of your question. Did you succeed with the problem in the first part? Please [edit] to ask one consistent question.

Comment: @kaylum@Vijay@Yunnosch I have edited the question and tried to make it more clear

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you open an existing file for writing, in contrast to appending? See the effect described here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen for using the "a"(write to end) / "w"(destroy contents) .

Comment: @Yunnosch can you detail about the appending part please

Comment: Even more than linking the specification and pointing out the core difference? Please try the effect of `"a"` instead of `"w"` and report.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you so much, i didn't know write destroys after execution...

Comment: Now that you know the solution, it should be easy for you to [edit] your question to focus on describing and demonstrating (with a MRE) the problem you want to discuss and make sure that your description of the symptoms includes the relevant details and no distraction.

Comment: Please turn the shown code into an actual [mre] and add a textual version of the helpful info from your screenshot picture of text, because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

Please see
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen on the effect of using the "a"(write to end) / "w"(destroy contents).

Your code uses "w", which will always start the files content afresh, i.e. empty for writing.
Using "a" instead should append to existing content and get you the desired two lines instead of one.